# AWS App-Sync (request failed with status code 403)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am trying to create a new API (app sync) when I am creating a schema
I got `request failed with status code 403`

```
creating DynamoDB tables. Please do not refresh...,
creating Schema. Please do not refresh...,
Request failed with status code 403
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked IAM permissions for your user? What happens if you try using CLI?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS app sync service automatically creates a new role when creating new data sources, so there is no permission to create a new role for my user.